# Android Game - Sprite speed seems to be different on different phones

Tags: android, performance, sprite

I am developing a android game in surfaceView. When i test the game on different devices the playerSprite seems to go faster on some devices as compared to the other. 
How do i accomodate for different devices when setting player speed programmatically?

if(MainActivity.slowSpeed == true){

```
             speedX = (float) (canvasWidth/266);

             speedY = (float)(canvasHeight/150);




         }




         if(MainActivity.fastSpeed == true){

             speedX = (float) (canvasWidth/192);

             speedY =(float) (canvasHeight/108);



         }
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question unless you describe your implementation and post some code.

Comment: @Egor I have pasted my code . I just set the speed of the object upfront and it stays the same throughout.  However on different devices the playing experience is different. On some devices the object seems to move faster and on the other it slows down. Although the frames achieved on these devices are almost similar . 34 frames per second approx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the framerate is not steady (like 30 or 60 frames a second), you should compensate every moving element in your game by a factor which you calculate from the actual framerate you achieved.

```
 achievedFramerate = 34.0f;    //The framerate you dynamically measure
 baseFramerate = 30.0f;        //The framerate at which your game is meant to be played
 framerateAdjustFactor = baseFramerate / achievedFramerate;
```

You use it somewhere in your game as such:

```
 playerX += speedX * framerateAdjustFactor;
```

So everywhere where something is moving, you compensate the movement by this factor. This way on a machine which is capable of 60 frames a second, everything will just move twice as slow per frame, which results in the game moving at exactly the same speed.

Make sure your framerate calculation is done EVERY frame, and must be done with an adequate precision.

Answer (score 0):

I would just measure times between `onDraw` calls and wait if it's too short.

```
while( t1 - t0 < MINIMUM_FRAME_TIME ){
    // you could put a short wait(#) here if you wanted.
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
t0 = t1;
```

t0, t1 and MINIMUM_FRAME_TIME are long values.

Comment: This method would eat a lot of processor cycles and burn through your battery. Better is to check the time difference and then let the thread sleep.